# Webpack: импортировать файл, путь к которому передан в качестве аргумента

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

В данном примере `ClassA` из файла **ClassA.js** парсит JSON из файла **Data.json** и отдаёт его экземпляру класса `ClassB` из файла **ClassB.js** в качестве аргумента:

### ClassA.js

```
import { data } from './every/time/different/path/Data.json'
import ClassB from './every1/time2/differenet3/path4/ClassB'

class A {
    constructor () {
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        let classB = new ClassB(parsedData);        
    }
}
```

Теперь я хочу, чтобы `classB` сам парсил JSON, а первым аргументом был не готовый JS-объект, а путь к файлу **Data.json**.

**ClassA.js**

```
import ClassB from './every1/time2/differenet3/path4/ClassB'

class ClassA {
    constructor() {
        let classB = ClassB('./every/time/different/path1/Data.json');
    }
}
```

**classB.js**

```
class ClassB {
    constructor(pathToDataJsonFile) {
        this.data = JSON.parse(require(pathToDataJsonFile));
    }

    get somethingBasedOnData() {
        return this.data.prop1 + this.data.prop2;
    }
}
```

Конечно, работать это не будет, потому что путь `./every/time/different/path/Data.json` указан относительно файла `ClassA.js`, но `ClassB.js` находится в другой директории. Как же следует указать правильный путь к **Data.json**?

Запрещённые приёмы:

- Импортировать файл **Data.json** внутри **ClassB.js** (`import { data } из файла'./every/time/different/path1/Data.json'`): всё, что касается **Data.json**, за исключением изначального знания пути к этому файлу, возлагается на **ClassB**. Предполагается, что в реальности будет создаваться отдельный экземпляр **ClassB** для каждого набора JSON-данных.
- Указывать в явном виде путь к **Data.json** относительно **ClassB.js** в качестве параметра : мы должны сами в уме вычислять путь к этому файлу вместо машины, что противоречит концепции программирования.

Comment: а потом это дело уедет в браузер и никаких json файлов там не будет? в доках вебпака есть глава lazy loading

Comment: @Daniel Khoroshko, понятно, что в браузер уедет собранный бандл и там уже никаких путей к файлам не будет. Как именно решит проблему предложенный Вами lazy loading?

Comment: require + абсолютный путь?

Comment: @MedvedevDev, я - за, только как получить абсолютный путь к файлу из относительного в Webpack?

Comment: вы не знаете где у вас файл лежит или по условию задачи нельзя строку с путем менять? клавиатура сломалась, с экранной сложно расписать, так что вот ссылка, думаю не сложно разобраться - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27512914/7815487

Comment: @MedvedevDev, я знаю, где лежит файл. ...Получается, что если я не хочу писать вручную абсолютный путь, то тогда его нужно вычислить в конфиге webpack, я правильно понял?

Comment: ну, не вычислить а просто зарезолвить (root/modules в зависимость от версии) корень приложения, тогда можно будет указывать путь "относительно" него.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, Почти понял! Это то есть свои модули можно будет импортировать как из `node_modules`, то есть без точки с косой чертой в начале пути?

Comment: именно, так же можно использовать alias для различных сущностей типа 'Views/Header/main.js', 'Models/Header/main.js', etc.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, Понял! Если хотите баллы репутации, то когда купите новую клавиатуруб то оформите, пожалуйста, ответ, и я Вам поставлю галочку и войтап.